# Designing a database for storing 500 million domain names with full text search

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm about to build an application that stores up to 500 million records of domain names.
I'll index the '.net' or '.com' part and strip the 'www' at the beginning.
So I believe the table would look like this:

```
domain_id | domain_name  | domain_ext
----------+--------------+-----------
1         | dropbox      | 2
2         | digitalocean | 2
```

domain_ext = 2 means it's a '.com' domain.

**The queries I'm about to perform:**:

1. I need to be able to insert new domains easily.
2. I also need to make sure I'm not inserting a duplication (each domain should have only 1 record), so I think to make `domain_name + domain_ext` as UNIQUE index (with MySQL - InnoDB).
3. Query domains in batches. For example: `SELECT * FROM tbl_domains LIMIT 300000, 600;`

What do you think? will that table hold hundreds of millions of records?
How about partitioning by first letter of the domain name, would that be good?
Let me know your suggestions, I'm open minded.

Comment: Did you think about using a better database to use "full text search"? Take a look into "cassandra db", "solr" or other kind of databases with good performance like "orient db".

Comment: Like I said, I'm open minded. After some thoughts I think I don't need full text search since I can use MySQL's unique index.

Comment: Then, I recommend you orientdb because you can do a lot of operations per seconds, it's very fast: http://orientdb.com/

Comment: So mail.somedomain.com and www.somedomain.com are the same for your needs? What about extentions like co.uk, or tv? Also, what about adresses where the .net leads to the same website as the .com extention? Should they be considered as 2 different domains?

Comment: @ZoharPeled , I do care about sub-domains (mail.somedomain.com). extensions like co.uk will have a different extension_id. Oh and...I don't care if two domains leads to the same website.

Comment: @JoseMato , OrientDB looks good, I'll check it out...!

Comment: so why strip the www? it's also a sub-domain...

Comment: True, but it's not the point of the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Partitioning is unlikely to provide any benefit.  Certainly if you are partitioning on the first letter.
- Don't use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` for batching.  Instead "remember where you left off".  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) for more details.
- If you have declared `domain_ext` to be `INT`, then I ask why?  `INT` takes 4 bytes.  So does `.com`.  Even if you counter with `SMALLINT` or `.uk`, I will counter-counter with "The small difference does not justify the complexity."

**Edit (on UNIQUE)**

A non-partitioned table can have a `UNIQUE` index.  (Note:  A `PRIMARY KEY` *is* a `UNIQUE` index.)  When you have a `UNIQUE` index, checking for uniqueness is virtually instantaneous, even for 500M rows.  (Drilling down about 5 levels of BTree is *very* fast.)

With `PARTITIONing`, every `UNIQUE` key must include the "partition key".  If the domain is *not* split, you cannot use `PARTITION BY RANGE`.  Splitting off the extension (top-level domain) as an `INT`, you could use `BY RANGE` or `BY LIST`.  The `UNIQUE` would be possible since the TLD is both the partition key and needed as part of the domain.  But it would not gain any performance.  A lookup would (1) pick the partition ("partition pruning"), then (2) drill down 4-5 levels of BTree to get to the row to check.

Conclusion:  Doing a uniqueness check, while possible in this case, will not be any faster with `PARTITIONing`.

Comment: Thanks @Rick James , nice post! I'll use that technique. One question: I wanted to use domain_ext column because it narrows down the amount of potential rows when doing a UNIQUE check. Am I wrong? Do you think it would be better to let MySQL to check against all the table instead of half of it since the extension_id is much faster index?

Comment: No benefit -- see Edit.